# What is the meaning of the phrase 'Here be dragons'?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does *here be dragons* mean in the example below?

> WARNING **Here be dragons.** Relative source binding can not only encourage
>   bad application practices, such as binding to things defined in codebehind
>   instead of following a pattern such as ViewModel, but also be hard
>   to debug, especially when you get into changes to DataContext set by external
>   consumers of your user control.

Comment: Hic sunt dracones

Comment: @Bog: and? Wouldn't you want the first google entry to be this very page?

Comment: What grammar 'rule' does this sentence use? And is it equal with 'Here *might be* dragons?'

Comment: @naxa See http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/66/9566

Answer (score 60, accepted):

"Here be Dragons" was a phrase frequently used in the 1700s and earlier by cartographers (map makers) on faraway, uncharted corners of the map. It was meant to warn people away from dangerous areas where sea monsters were believed to exist. It's now used metaphorically to warn people away from unexplored areas or untried actions. There are no actual dragons, but it is still dangerous.

Comment: I'd like to see some evidence that this text was "frequently" put on maps in the 1700s.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. It's one of those things that "everyone knows", which turns out to be not true.If I remember correctly, it only ever appeared on one map. The answer is, however, correct, as this is the legend the question is referring to.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: When you find such evidence, you might use it to support the contention in your own answer that there was "a tendency for old maps to be 'embellished' with ... the legend ..."

Comment: @Robusto - it isn't contentious that old maps used to be embellished, just not with these specific words.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons

Comment: This answer is correct in spirit but inaccurate according to wikipedia so -1 until it is fixed.

Comment: @Robusto: I didn't actually check anything before I wrote my answer. I knew old maps sometimes had serpents, Anemoi (wind gods), etc., partly just to "fill out" the unknown corners. As I implied, I was somewhat sceptical that any cartographer worth his salt would actually *write* "Here be dragons". Having seen the Wikipedia article I now wish I'd put it a bit more strongly.

Comment: You could simply add to your answer that this legend is not factual, but since people believe it to be true, the phrase has the same effect.

Comment: @Neil Fein: I did indeed do that. Even though I now know it's effectively untrue, I really like the "old maps" origin. If I was watching a swashbuckling adventure movie featuring an antique map I think I'd be positively disappointed if it didn't have "Here be dragons" somewhere in a corner! :)

Comment: @Sverre Rabbelier:  I wonder if such signs are posted anywhere on the island of Komodo?

Comment: Your answer is still untrue, as it claims the phrase was used frequently on maps. I submitted an edit, perhaps this will help?

Comment: An analogous phrase is "hic sunt leones", with the same meaning http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons#Other_creatures_on_maps
Here you can also read about some examples of real maps containing this and similar phrases.

Answer (score 33):

It's a jocular archaism. I wouldn't like to say it was ever really spoken in earnest, by a speaker who genuinely feared he was entering land so little known it might contain dragons.

It may have got a bit of extra currency from the tendency for old maps to be "embellished" with drawings. Unexplored areas (land, sea, or unknown) would often be decorated with serpents, and perhaps the legend **Here be dragons**.

Today it's just a jokey way of saying "There are/may be some really scary things here!". In OP's context, really difficult technical problems.

**LATER**: Having consulted Wikipedia on this one, I should say the only relevant ancient usage known is the [Hunt-Lenox Globe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt-Lenox_Globe) (early 1500s), with the Latin **HC SVNT DRACONES** (*hic sunt dracones, here are dragons*) on the eastern coast of Asia.

The earliest reference I can find is [this from 1892](http://books.google.com/books?id=twQiAQAAIAAJ&q=%22here%20be%20dragons%22&dq=%22here%20be%20dragons%22&hl=en&ei=k-0_TsCYKISx8gOBy7X9Ag&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBDge) claiming cartographers from the 1300s used the phrase, but [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=here%20be%20dragons&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) strongly suggests the myth didn't become widespread until quite recently.

But it's a nice legend, so I'll keep my "perhaps" at the end of the second paragraph.

Answer (score 6):

“Here be dragons” is used to denote dangerous or unexplored territories (see on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons)).

I assume that in your case, it means:

> WARNING. If you're skiing out of bounds, you'll be on your own, you may encounter problems and it will be hard to come back.

where “out of bounds” means “not following patterns” and “come back” means “debug”.

Comment: While you're explaining the phrases in your alternative version, you might also mention that by "skiing out of bounds", you mean "using relative source binding". But it's not a usage I've heard before (though I have heard people say "skiing off-piste" metaphorically).