# What is the structure of "a goal remote in the pursuit is so easy to lose sight of"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis

> **A goal remote in the pursuit** is so easy to lose sight of.

What does "a goal remote in the pursuit" mean here? I don't understand it structure-wise.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: I would say that it means a goal that you are working toward (pursuing) is still far off. If you're asking about the sentence structure, the *remote in the pursuit* part is an [adjective phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase) that modifies *a goal.*

Comment: @SoylentGreen: I was wondering if birdman1234 wanted the grammatical structure or the global structure of the sentence.

Comment: @birdman1234: No, I don't think so. I think it means "a goal you are trying to accomplish which is in its infancy".

Comment: I haven't heard that construct before, but it sounds like "[Can't see the forest for the trees](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can%27t+see+the+forest+for+the+trees)".

Comment: Why on *earth* have two people closevoted as Primarily Opinion-based? They may not like the usage, but how can anyone claim it doesn't have an analysable structure?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the effect of this rather curious construction is to give an "archaic" flavour to a latter-day "pseudo-adage". Structurally, *remote* is an adjective modifying the *goal*. Normally it would come *before* the noun, but here you could say it's a [post-positive adjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-positive_adjective) (coming *after* the noun).

To further complicate things, *remote* is modified by the additional adjectival clause *in the pursuit*.

Or (as per the Wkipedia link above), you could say it applies [elision](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsElision.htm) to the underlying structure...

> *A goal [**that is**] remote in the pursuit is so easy to lose sight of.*

---

As to *meaning*, it's just saying if your goal is too ambitious/far in the future, you risk losing sight of it (being distracted by day-to-day activities you only undertook originally in pursuit of that goal).

---

EDIT: Comments (and a downvote!) may indicate not everyone is happy with the basic format...

> an **X** that is **Y** in the **Z**
>   *a [noun] that is [adjective] in the [noun/gerund]*

As I said initially, it's a "curious" construction, which I would *not* advise less competent speakers to experiment with. But although I wouldn't say it's exactly ["productive"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_%28linguistics%29) today, here are a few related examples to show the basic format[s] are used elsewhere...

> [**broad in the beam**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/broad-in-the-beam) *(jocular "wide-hipped", of nautical origins)*
>   [**far in the offing**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22far+in+the+offing%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) *(usually, in **negated** forms*)
>    [**masterpiece in the making**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20lady%20in%20the%20wooing%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22masterpiece%20in%20the%20making%22&tbm=bks) *(i.e. - in the process of being made)*
>   [**long in the writing**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22long%20in%20the%20making%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22long%20in%20the%20writing%22&tbm=bks) *(i.e. - where "the writing" is a lengthy process)*
>   [**long in the construction**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22long%20in%20the%20making%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22long%20in%20the%20construction%22&tbm=bks) *(just to show that the noun isn't always a gerund form)*

Comment: 'Remote in the pursuit' sounds pseud in the extreme. 'A remote goal' is sufficient. There are only 5 hits on Google.

Comment: @Edwin: So tell us something new. Those five Google hits consist of two to this question plus two irrelevant accidental collocations (one duplicated). But the structurally-identical *far in the offing* is [far from dead yet](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=far+in+the+offing&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfar%20in%20the%20offing%3B%2Cc0). And there might be a lot of false positives, but [good in the eating](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22good+in+the+eating%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) certainly exists.

Comment: Try googling "tiger in the pursuit" -"in the pursuit of", and substituting other animals. I'd say it's just not used. And notice that the construction here is of the form 'Adj in the Y'. Examples of regularly-used constructions of this type are fairly rare and unpredictable. "Remote in the chasing" and "remote in the hunt" show no Google hits, though 'in the hunt' is a well known collocation. 'In the pursuit' usually parallels 'in the 100 metres'. Finding a few examples of a string does not guarantee acceptability.

Comment: But tiger in the pursuit means the tiger we are chasing? the tiger remote in the pursuit is "we are chasing this tiger but its still remote." ?

Comment: You can't just string together a few related-looking words and demand that people come up with the meaning you desire. 'Tiger in the pursuit' is undefined to me.

Comment: @Edwin: I think that's rather overstating the case. Granted, it's not a common format, but I think one could reasonably expect competent native speakers to understand, say, *a deer in the pursuit* to mean *a deer [which is in the process of] being pursued*.

Comment: @FF: I can understand quite a lot of the babblings of infants. That doesn't mean that I am going to encourage them in their continued use of non-standard English.

Comment: @Edwin: I pretty much agree, but so far as I'm concerned if people want to *learn* English, they should go to ELL. I warned it was a "curious" construction in the original text, and amplified on that in light of your comments, but I've no objection to *competent speakers* pushing the boundaries of the language. In fact, I quite enjoy it when it's well done. I'd guess OP doesn't really fall into that category - but he should by know have all the information he needs to make a decision, and although I think the "original" is clumsy, *...is easily lost to the sight* doesn't sound too bad to me.

Comment: @FF I've no objection to pushing the bounds when done sympathetically, but we've got to be careful not to confuse people with 'nice turn of phrase' when they're reading 'this is what the expression is normally taken to mean'.

Comment: @Edwin: Yeah, well, like I say - people who're likely to be confused by this level of answer shouldn't be here in the first place (they should be on ELL). I mean to say - *"this rather curious construction"* in my first sentence seems like a reasonable warning to me. Would you have me start off with [WARNING Here be dragons](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37086/), or even avoid deconstructing the usage at all on the grounds that it's uncommon, complex, and liable to be misused?

Comment: For something with 2 independent Google hits, I'd say we need to point out it's non-standard rather than rather curious.

Comment: @Edwin: Now you *know* I'm like a dog with a bone on things like this! What does it matter that OP's exact words aren't "common"? That doesn't make them "non-standard". How exactly is *remote in the pursuit* structurally different to *long in the writing/construction/etc.?*

Comment: If you look up 'non-standard' you'll see that accepted structure isn't the only requirement for a string to not be considered 'non-standard'. 'A goal remote in the pursuit' certainly conforms to a grammatical pattern for which there are acceptable examples, but then so does 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously'. And 'An objective distant in the hunting'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12747/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-edwin-ashworth)