# “All X-related things” / “All things X-related” / “All things X related”?

Tags: word-choice, punctuation, hyphenation, compounds

My French origins (probably?) would have me intuitively write “all X-related things”, but it seems usage favours the construct “all things X-related”, or even without a hyphen: “all things X related” (see [Google results for “all related things”](http://www.google.com/search?q=all+related+things)).

So, are any of these incorrect? Which one would be best?

(If that's any help, I want to say “software engineer with a passion for all things user related”. Also in this particular case, should I write “user**s** related” instead?)

Thanks!

Comment: related: [Why do some adjectives follow the nouns they modify?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42319/why-do-some-adjectives-follow-the-nouns-they-modify) Socce - I'd have thought if you're a native Francophone you'd be more drawn to *"all things X-related"*, since French usually puts the adjective *after* the noun. I recall asking about [“ma jolie femme” vs “ma femme jolie”](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2134/) on SO French.

Comment: @FumbleFingers then it's probably more like, the way that from a French culture I learnt to _always_ place adjectives before the noun in English (which was insisted upon because unintuitive to us)... Thanks for the related question, which shows me that there are exceptions. :)

Comment: @ Socce: I see what you mean (good point). You may find it interesting to note Google Book claims 1680 hits for ["and all things related" -"related to"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22and+all+things+related%22+-%22related+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (where the excluded term should get rid of most "false positives" not relevant to our context here). By contrast, it claims only 173 instances of ["and all related things"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22and+all+related+things%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). It's almost a "fixed phrase", using non-standard word order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*X-related* is not required to come before or after what it modifies. It is *all things* which is idiomatic, and makes you question the word position.

The Biblical *[all things to all men](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/29250.html)* may explain its popularity, or to a lesser extent, *all things must pass*. Regardless of origin, however, *all things* remains a very frequent collocation, found in such expressions as *[all things being equal](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/all-things-being-equal)* or *[of all things!](http://www.americanidioms.net/of-all-things/)* The flagship news program on National Public Radio (US) is *[All Things Considered](http://www.npr.org/programs/all-things-considered/)*, and for an extensive review of American stereotypes of Scotland, there is the old *Saturday Night Live* sketch about a store named *[All Things Scottish (and Pizza)](http://www.nbc.com/saturday-night-live/digital-shorts/video/all-things-scottish/1353543/)*.

To insert an adjective before *things* violates no grammatical rule. One could conceivably say *We need more purple things for Mardis Gras decorations*, or *What are all the round things on the left of the banner?* In a CV, however, I would avoid vague words like *things* in favor of specific terminology.

> Software engineer with a passion for all things user-related.
>
> Software engineer with a passion for user-related design and development.

(The term would indeed be *user-related*, as with *user access*, *user error*, and so on.)

*All things* is somewhat more grandiose than *everything*, and sometimes they can substitute for one another. One could plausibly say *I'm interested in everything Turkish* and *I'm interested in all things Turkish* in conversation. On the other hand, *You're all things I want in a woman* sounds stilted, and *I'd like a pizza with all things on it* will get you a quizzical look. And no pizza.

Comment: Thanks for the complete, in-depth and pleasant to read explanation. Using the vague “things” in my case is also some kind of “[strategic sloppiness](http://www.linkedin.com/today/post/article/20140108153547-32124898-how-spelling-mistakes-and-bad-e-mail-etiquette-can-help-you-get-ahead)” -- a personal choice, I'll admit.
For future readers, the hyphen-or-no-hyphen question was also adressed in [_Should I use “ related” or “-related”_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2908).

Comment: I don't *strongly* disagree with any of this, but I wouldn't really say your illustrations show that "all things" is *in itself* an idiomatic usage. It's just a trivial literal collocation, *except* in the specific form "**all things/matters X-related**". Which I venture to suggest is at the very least an idiomatic "fixed form" - which you could [either characterise as "post-positive adjective" or deletion of "that are"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/148277/2637).